# When creating a Java UDP server, how many bytes do I allocate for the packet buffer?

Tags: java, udp, byte, buffer

```
public DatagramPacket(byte[] buf,int length)
// Constructs a DatagramPacket for receiving packets of length length.
```

Using the vanilla Java classes for a UDP server (DatagramSocket), how am I supposed to calculate the buffer size for an incoming packet? 
I have looked through the javadocs, and there seems to be a method called *getReceiveBufferSize()*, but I really don't know what I would use the returned data for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have no other clue from your app/protocol requirements/spec, 64K is a good size - it will never be too small.